# Recording iOS Simulator produces empty files

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ios11, xcode9, screen-capture

I am trying to record the screen of my iOS 11.4 simulator with `xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo recording.mov`. This creates a file with that name, but unfortunately that file always has the size of 0 byte. Playing around with the `--type` parameter did not help either. Occasionally there was a playable file, which also was corrupted to a degree, as this file had a distorted look to it when opened in QuickTime. VLC could not play it at all.

I am using Xcode 9.4.1 on a 2014 MacBook Pro with discrete GPU, so Metal is supported.

Does anyone have suggestions to solve my problem?

Comment: You should look at @Harish's answer, it solved my problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a timing bug in video recording that could result in 0-byte files on some systems.  I'm sorry, but there is unfortunately no workaround.  This should be addressed with changes in Xcode 10 Beta 3+.

Comment: Indeed it's failing for me in Xcode 9.4.1 and Xcode 10 Beta 2, but I just tried Xcode Beta 4 and it worked, although the video produced had some strange glitches as if the image was melting :(

Answer (score 2):

I had that same issue and was scratching my head over that for days. The fix turns out to be simple though. Make sure you press `Control + C` and quit the simulator. Once you quit the simulator it starts to actually produce the recording.

Comment: You just saved my life !

Comment: The key step is quitting the simulator. This worked for me with Xcode 9.4 but there were a lot of visual artifacts in the video

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the device you want to record, and "booted" isn't valid.

Run this to see what's booted:

```
xcrun simctl list | grep Booted
```

In my case I see:

```
iPhone X (D3DB2489-B630-42AB-A615-A2F07F6F6876) (Booted)
```

To record this device:

```
xcrun simctl io D3DB2489-B630-42AB-A615-A2F07F6F6876 recordVideo ~/simrecord.mov
```

Here's example output from my terminal:

```
[ ~] xcrun simctl list | grep Booted
    iPhone X (D3DB2489-B630-42AB-A615-A2F07F6F6876) (Booted)
[ ~] xcrun simctl io D3DB2489-B630-42AB-A615-A2F07F6F6876 recordVideo ~/simrecord.mov
GVA encoder info: recomputed for fps: 11.353266, gop size in pics: 340, gop size in sec: 30.000000 
Recording... (Press CTRL+C to stop)
^C
Recording completed.
[ ~] ls -lrt | tail -1
-rw-r--r--    1 shawd  staff  32933285 Jun 29 16:34 simrecord.mov
```

One other thing to mention is that you can also record the simulator with Quicktime on the Mac pretty easily.  That's what most people do.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but unfortunately this does give me the same 0 byte sized file.

Comment: You know you have to stop the recording before the file is written, yes?  Updated my answer with terminal output.